# Friend Based System in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, chat

So I currently have a real-time chat application up and running with node and `socket.io`. What I would like to do from here is let users create an account and search for other users based on their usernames. Then, they can add them as a friend via request to start chatting.

I have looked around the web to try and answer this question, but cannot find any solid starting point. I am brand new to `node.js`, `express`, and `socket.io`, and would love some help with this issue.

If you could point me in the right direction as to how I can create a friend based system using node, that would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: This question is far too broad for stack overflow.  You've included no detailed spec for what you're trying to build and you're asking an incredibly broad question with no specifics.  A "friend-based system" is not a known commodity that says exactly what you're trying to do.  You need to find one aspect of what you're trying to build, research the options for making that part, then ask a very specific question about the parts of that exact feature that you don't understand.  We can't design a whole product for you here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for the lack of detail. I wasn't asking for an entire solution, just some sort of idea as to how this system could work. This should've been stated in the question, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too think this is a broad question but I will try to give you the glimpse of a technological aspect of what you are trying to do.

First of all, you should have a user management system, including login, signup, forget password etc. You can use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) for this. Now, you have a complete user management system, you can start further.

If you are willing to friend request/accept feature that eventually control the chat system, You might wanna create a database structure like below.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Schema defines how chat messages will be stored in MongoDB
const FriendsSchema = new Schema({
  participants: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }],
  requestTo: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
  accepted: {tyoe: Boolen, default:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Friends', FriendsSchema);
```

You can check this database to create a friendship request, check friendship between two users etc. And another thing you shoud do in database is to create model for chats. To save messages, Like below:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  friendshipId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Friends'
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  seen: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  delivered: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
},
  {
    timestamps: true // Saves createdAt and updatedAt as dates. createdAt will be our timestamp.
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

Now, for the real-time chat system you should integrate both socket.io and databases. You can do it like below code.

```js
var http   = require('http')

var redis   = require('redis')
var client   = redis.createClient()


module.exports = (app) => {
 const server  = http.createServer(app)
 const io   = require('socket.io').listen(server)

 io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('sendChat', (user, msg, messageId) => {
   client.get(user, function(err, socketId){
    io.to(socketId).emit('updateChat', socket.username, msg, messageId)
   })
    })
  socket.on('delivered', (user, messageId) => {
   client.get(user, function(err, socketId){
    io.to(socketId).emit('delivered', messageId)
   })
  })
  socket.on('seen', (user, messageId) => {
   client.get(user, function(err, socketId){
    io.to(socketId).emit('seen', messageId)
   })
  })
  socket.on('adduser', (username) => {
   client.set(username, socket.id, function(err){
    socket.username = username
    io.sockets.emit('updateOnlineUser', username)
   })
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   client.del(socket.username)
   io.sockets.emit('updateOfflineUser', socket.username)
  })
 })
}
```

What happens above? It basically create a connection to client and when the client sends a addUser event to server it stores user in radis store. And when messages are transferred through socket, by sending sendChat event, it sends events to another chat user. You will also need to save this chat to database as well.

And when users do not want to send message to inactive users, which are not connected through socket. You must implement endpoints for messaging tasks. For more info please follow through [this open source project](https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter).

Comment: Thanks so much man. This is exactly what I needed, I just didn't really know where to begin to create something like this. In your opinion, would it be better to manage the chat data with MongoDB or Firebase? I'm not exactly for sure which would be better for managing users and chat data.

Comment: Firebase, as much as I know, is a backend service for mobile app. Which is not just a database service rather a whole complete package of backend. So, If you are a backend developer you need to dive more into MongoDB. If you are a mobile app developer and do not want backend bother than you can surely use firebase.

Comment: Okay, I've decided I'm going to go with MongoDB. In your chat code, what exactly is Redis being used for? I've heard of it before and am not familiar with its use.

Comment: It is in-memory key value storage, here, it is used to store information of user's socketID.